# How to change Xcode Swift Minimum OS Version?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

With Xcode, how to change a projects minimum OS Version?
Error: I need Version 15.2 but have 14.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the iOS deployment target to the version you want (in this case, version 15.2). This field is located in the project config. In my example, the project name is called "test":

[image]